# Numerical calculation of Chern number for low energy continuum models

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, topology, topological-insulators

Can Fukui method be employed for the Chern number calculation in a low-energy continuum model? Let's consider the low-energy continuum version of the Kane-Mele model. If not what are some other ways one can try? Thanks.